# what is placement groups in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-elb

I am new to AWS and trying to understand placement groups in AWS. What is the difference between cluster and spread placement and why are those needed ? how do application benefit from placement groups

Answer (score 3):

From [AWS EC2 - Placement Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html):

> **Cluster** placement groups are recommended for applications that benefit from low network latency, high network throughput, or both, and if the majority of the network traffic is between the instances in the group.
>
> **Spread** placement groups are recommended for applications that have a small number of critical instances that should be kept separate from each other.

Choosing a placement group allows you to specify how your system should be arranged on AWS hardware. Without choosing one, you have no control over said arrangement.